# Is it security risk to host CS:GO server on my PC?

Tags: server, ports, gaming

I have quite good hardware in my PC and an optic fiber connection. I opened a CS:GO (Counter Strike Global Offensive) server on it, and made it public. The IP for connecting to this server is my public IP address.

I set a strong password to the router admin (24+ characters), and I made sure that I have no risky/unwanted ports open. So in short, except for DDoS attacks, is this setup risky in any way?

Answer (score 8):

The biggest risk is probably a **0-day** or simply an **unpatched vulnerability** in the server software of CS:GO.

Against a 0-day you are rather helpless. You can give **the user running the CS:GO process as little permissions as possible**. If your server gets compromised, the attacker can only act with the permission of this user, as long as he doesn't exploit a local privilege escalation as well. Being the victim of such a 0-day is not very likely, but it always is a residual risk when exposing a service to the internet.

To avoid getting compromised via an unpatched vulnerability, well, **patch your CS:GO server regularly**. Find out where users are informed about new patches and vulnerabilities and **monitor these sources**. If you cannot patch immediately, consider shutting the server down until you get to patch it.

In case you do not offer the server 24/7 and mostly play yourself, **shut the server down, when it is not needed**. Reducing the attack surface also means reducing the time the service is available.

Comment: thank you so much! 
i checked and my server is up to date and i will keep up and check regularly for new updates.

about limiting permissions, is simple software restriction policy would do a good work in this term?

beyond 0-day, is there any other attacks i'm vulnerable to?

Comment: As an example, [Zero-Days in Counter-Strike Client Used to Build Major Botnet](https://threatpost.com/zero-days-counter-strike-botnet/142823/)

Comment: You can also consider hosting the server on a VM for an added layer of insulation

Comment: @rdmptn I second that. A VM is a great protection from 0-days on the server software, since VM escapes are relatively rare

Comment: There is a brand new issue concerning CS:GO, that may require immediate attention: https://twitter.com/BafDyce/status/1253035403470307328